# Setting MinOccurs to 0 on a WSDL

Tags: c#, wsdl

I'm quite new to WSDL's and trying to understand how the pattern still works. I've created a simple addition function on C# with the following code:

```
namespace mathsService
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Summary description for mathService
    /// </summary>
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
    // To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
    // [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
    public class mathService : WebService
    {

        [WebMethod]
        public int Add(int a, int b, int c = 0)
        {
            return (a + b + c);
        }
    }
}
```

What I'm trying to learn is how to make variable C optional. I'd like to give the option of passing in either 2 numbers or three but I cannot seem to set the minOccurs to 0 for parameter C.

This is what I keep seein in my WSDL:

```
<s:sequence>
<s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="a" type="s:int"/>
<s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="b" type="s:int"/>
<s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="c" type="s:int"/>
</s:sequence>
```

Would anyone be able to suggest how I can set minOccurs= 0 for variable c and if possible how to set it to be nullable?

Comment: And you also tried  `int? c`?

Comment: Thank you - added your suggestion and I can now see the nillable tag howver minOccur is still 1

Comment: I'm not sure you can with value types, because using optional parameters implies am overloaded style of work as WS-I doesn't really support overloading. I'm prepared to be wrong about it, but I think if you're looking to provide a two-parameter version you might have to add another method with a different name (or with the same name if your rename it in the webmethod attrib arguments), that calls your 3 parameter version and supplies 0 as C. Decalring C as a string (that you parse and default to 0 on failure) might be the simplest route

Comment: Thanks @CaiusJard
Explanation seems reasonable enough! If you'd like to make your comments an answer - I can mark it as accepted?

Comment: I do like to be a bit more authoritative with my answers normally so I'll post one as soon as I can do a bit of research and back up my assumptions! I suspect that the simplistic rule set of "value types are min occurs 1", and "nullables are declared nillable" may be the case but Ill look into it when I can and post up if I find anything substantive